# Cordova white screen on release build

Tags: android, cordova, phaser-framework

I got this from cordova log:

```
$ adb logcat | grep CordovaLog  

>I/CordovaLog( 2305): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)  

>D/CordovaLog( 2305): file:///android_asset/www/js/phaser.min.js: Line 7 : %c %c %c Phaser v2.0.2 - Canvas - WebAudio  %c %c  http://phaser.io  %c %c ♥%c♥%c♥   

>D/CordovaLog( 2305): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 42 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
```

All work fine in debug but got a white screen in the release apk...

Answer (score 1):

Have you added an en external script to load without whitelisting it?  The script will be blocked so you can end up with null objects like you have.